# How to test React 'componentDidUpdate()' and 'shouldComponentUpdate()' in Jest/Enzyme testing?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to get the coverage of all my React components above 80%, but a lot of the lines of coded still needing coverage are enclosed in lifecycle methods, such as componentDidUpdate(). What would be the best way to go about testing the code to get 100% coverage? We need to use Enzyme.mount() since most of our components are parent components. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461011/how-to-mock-a-react-component-lifecycle-method-with-jest-and-enzyme check this answer. You will have to mock the methods

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock a React component lifecycle method with Jest and Enzyme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461011/how-to-mock-a-react-component-lifecycle-method-with-jest-and-enzyme)